# Issue with Vue.js : Doesn't display data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-directives

I'm learning `Vue.js` framework and I'm making some tries in order to handle this JavaScript framework.

My example is very simple, but I don't overcome to display `data {}` according to `.html` and `.js` files.

This is my **.html file** :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test de Vue.js</title>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id='test'>
        <p>{{ texte }}</p>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

And my **.js file** located in the same directory :

```
var vm = new Vue ({
    el : '#test',
    data : {
        texte : 'Ceci est un premier test en Vue.js'
    }
});
```

But, I don't know why my browser displays this :

[image]

Thank you so much

Comment: @Derek Yes you can see `script src="test.js"></script>` in my HTML file

Comment: Move your script to the bottom of the page. `test.js` is running before the HTML is rendered. And also the scripts are in reverse order.

Comment: @RolandStarke Oh ok ! I have to load CDN in first time, then my .js script

Comment: @Bert Thank you very much ! It's a very newbie issue ..

Comment: No worries, we are all new at some point :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your scripts are in incorrect order. You have to include Vue.js first, then your script as second, because your script references `Vue` object, which is defined in `vue.js`.

Also, while `vue.js` can be included in `<head>`, your Vue model definition should go into the `<body>` tag, after the target element, otherwise, it will not work.

```
<head>
    ...
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="test">...</div>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Ok ! Right it works now ! It's really a newbie issue .. I'm sorry :/ Thank you !

Comment: I have to move my .js script outside of HTML header ;)